# Downloading a website using python

Tags: python, web-scraping, web-crawler

How can I download a complete website with a certain prefix like : https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/
I want to download every url that contains the above prefix

Comment: You've tagged web crawler, so have you search for web crawler Python libraries? Tried any?

Comment: use scrapy library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using `ubuntu` then use below command

```
wget -r -np https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/
```

If you are using windows then use [htttrack](https://www.httrack.com/) to download website for offline.

> Note: Do not use these for copyrighted websites